# Custom Opsworks layer fails while deploying new Postgresql server

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I'm following [this](http://blog.growthrepublic.com/creating-rails-application-host-using-aws-opsworks-and-chef/) guide to create a custom Postgresql layer within Opsworks to build a server for my Ruby on Rails app. I'm using this custom JSON as provided in the blog post:

```
{
  "postgresql" : {
    "password" : {
      "postgres" : "unhackablepassword"
    },
    "contrib" : {
      "packages" : ["postgresql-contrib-9.2"],
      "extensions" : ["hstore"]
    }
  }
}
```

The following custom cookbooks are used (git://github.com/growthrepublic/cookbooks.git)

- postgresql::contrib
- postgresql::ruby
- postgresql::server
- postgresql

The instance setup fails with this error message:

```
[2014-01-08T20:36:49+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::Package: package[postgresql-contrib-9.2] (postgresql::contrib line 24) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::Package: No version specified, and no candidate version available for postgresql-contrib-9.2
```

I'm new to Chef and Opsworks, does any one have any idea why it's failing?

Thanks!
Francis

Comment: Did you try running apt-get update?

Comment: @enricostn no, unfortunately...

Comment: @Rob3 nope haven't looked at the problem in a while...

Answer (score 0):

I've had success by adding the OS Package: postgresql-server-dev-9.3